# How to get a String Value from a void view in android?

Tags: android, string, button, void

I am trying to get the value of the Strings **firstChoice** and **secondChoice** from my Button onClick method below and use it in the same class. The problem is that I know you can't return a String value from a void method. Please take a look at what I have below:

```
 public class Question extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        Choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Choice4);
        Choice1.setOnClickListener(Question.this);

        Choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Choice5);
        Choice2.setOnClickListener(Question.this);

        firstChoice;
        secondChoice;

    public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()) {
              case R.id.Choice4:
                  showSelectPicksDialog();
                  Button b = (Button)view;
                String firstChoice = b.getText().toString();

                break;

              case R.id.Choice5:
                  showSelectPicksDialog2();
                  Button v = (Button)view;
                String secondChoice = v.getText().toString();// 
                break;

              default:
                break;
            }
          }
```

Is there a way I can get those values? As it is right now, When I try to call the values in my on Create method, I get the error saying that firstChoice and secondChoice "cannot be resolved to a type".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, you can use a class variable for instance:

```
public class Question extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    String firstChoice;    
    String secondChoice;    
    Button choice1;
    Button choice2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question);

        choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Choice4);
        choice1.setOnClickListener(Question.this);

        choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Choice5);
        choice2.setOnClickListener(Question.this);

        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.Choice4:
                showSelectPicksDialog();
                Button b = (Button)view;
                firstChoice = b.getText().toString();
                break;

            case R.id.Choice5:
                showSelectPicksDialog2();
                Button v = (Button)view;
                secondChoice = v.getText().toString();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying this right now. It should get the values of the firstChoice and secondChoice variables correct? Even if the public void onClick(View view) is a void?

Comment: Yes, `firstChoice` and `secondChoice` aren't being returned, so the `void` return type doesn't matter.